# clang does not warn for "defined but not used" in header, gcc does

Tags: c++, gcc, clang++

I came across some differences in how clang and gcc warns about unused variables.

```
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2
```

In foo.h

```
const int f = 3;
```

In foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"

const int a = 2;

int main() {
    int i;
    return 0;
}
```

I have

```
$ clang -o foo foo.cpp -Wall -Wunused-variable -Wunused-const-variable
foo.cpp:7:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
    int i;
        ^
foo.cpp:4:11: warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const int a = 2;
          ^
2 warnings generated.

$ gcc -o foo foo.cpp -Wall -Wunused-variable -Wunused-const-variable
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:7:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int i;
         ^
foo.cpp: At global scope:
foo.cpp:4:11: warning: ‘a’ defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
 const int a = 2;
           ^
In file included from foo.cpp:1:0:
foo.h:1:11: warning: ‘f’ defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
 const int f = 3;
```

I have a few questions:

Why is gcc complaining about the constant in the header? Isn't it common to put constants for your clients in there? How I can make clang behave like gcc?

Comment: Unused variable frequently means an error somewhere, hence the compiler warnings. Different compilers warn differently (the spec does not define this behavior, obviously).

Comment: What if you had `bar.cpp` in your program too that includes `foo.h` but doesn't use `f`? Do you really want a warning for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How I can make clang behave like gcc?

I think only by reporting this surprising clang bug and waiting for the fix. (It's still present in clang 7).

The translation unit defined by your `foo.cpp` must be the same as the file
produced by pre-processing it:

```
$ clang -E -P foo.cpp >foo.ii
$ cat foo.ii
const int f = 3;

const int a = 2;

int main() {
    int i;
    return 0;
}
```

with:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 6.0.1-svn330209-1~exp1~20180427232138.77 (branches/release_60)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

But clang 6 messes up:

```
$ clang -o foo foo.cpp -Wall -Wunused-variable -Wunused-const-variable
foo.cpp:6:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
    int i;
        ^
foo.cpp:3:11: warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const int a = 2;
          ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Whereas:

```
$ clang -o foo foo.ii -Wall -Wunused-variable -Wunused-const-variable
foo.ii:6:9: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
    int i;
        ^
foo.ii:1:11: warning: unused variable 'f' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const int f = 3;
          ^
foo.ii:3:11: warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const int a = 2;
          ^
3 warnings generated.
```

which now agrees with:

```
$ gcc -o foo foo.ii -Wall -Wunused-variable -Wunused-const-variable
foo.ii: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.ii:6:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int i;
         ^
foo.ii: At global scope:
foo.ii:3:11: warning: ‘a’ defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
 const int a = 2;
           ^
foo.ii:1:11: warning: ‘f’ defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
 const int f = 3;
           ^
```

**Later**

> why does the warning apply to constants in the header when this can be part of a library?

*header files* (and *libraries*) are not things that the compiler
recognizes. The *preprocessor* recognizes header files, by:

```
#include <headername>
...
#include "headername"
```

Using its specified or default search paths (`-I dir`), the preprocessor
resolves `headername` to `/some/actual/headername` and pastes the contents
of `/some/actual/headername` in place of the `#include` directive in the *translation unit*
that is consumed by the compiler. That translation unit is free of all preprocessor
directives. The compiler does not consume:

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

const int a = 2;

int main() {
    int i;
    return 0;
```

}

It consumes:

**foo.ii**

```
const int f = 3;

const int a = 2;

int main() {
    int i;
    return 0;
}
```

The clang behaviour you have observed implies that, internally, the tool
virtualizes the demarcation between *preprocessing* and *compiling* -
which actually is a routine historical practice in C/C++ implementations - but has introduced
this bug in the virtual demarcation. Whatever it is really doing with the source
code, it is not precisely the same as first preprocessing it, then compiling the
output of preprocessing; and it *should be*.

So *defining constants in header files* is not a practice to which a C++ implementation
can extend any special charity. If you are writing a library that exposes constants
in its API header, `bar.h`, and you do not want the users of that library to be at risk of
unused-variable warnings through failing to reference every constant defined in
`bar.h` in every compilation that `#include`s it, then you *will not* define those
constants just *as* `const` variables in `bar.h`. You will do one of three other things:

Define the constants as members of an `enum` or `enum class`:

```
enum class E : int {
    F = 3
    //...
};
```

Or, *declare* the constants `extern` in `bar.h` but *define* them in a library source file<sup>1</sup>:

**bar.h**

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

extern const int f;

#endif
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "bar.h"

const int f = 3;
```

Or, define the constants as preprocessor macros:

```
#define F 3
```

in the old-school C way. Which you won't, because in C++ we shun the preprocessor
if we can.

---

[1] How does `extern` avert the warning? Because `const` filescope variables are
implicitly `static` in C++ (though not in C), and the compiler never considers
an `extern` variable eligible for *unused* diagnostics because you are telling
it that the variable may be referenced in code provided to the linker
that the compiler cannot cannot see.

Comment: Will probably mark this as the correct. But I have another question - why does the warning apply to constants in the header when this can be part of a library? Or is this the supposed behavior of `unused-const-variable`?

Comment: @IvanKalchev See extended answer.